# Display all matches from preg match

Tags: php, regex

How can display all the results instead of just the first match from the preg match?

This is the content of $show:

```
<a href="http://website.com/one">One</a>
<a href="http://website.com/two">Two</a>
<a href="http://website.com/three">Three</a>
```

This is the PHP code:

```
preg_match("/<a href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)<\/a>/", $show, $display);
$xml = "<name>".$display[2]."</name><link>".$display[1]."</link>";
echo $xml;
```

The output is:

```
<name>One</name><link>http://website.com/one</link>
```

But I want it to display all the results like this:

```
<name>One</name><link>http://website.com/one</link>
<name>Two</name><link>http://website.com/two</link>
<name>Three</name><link>http://website.com/three</link>
```

this is the output of print_r($display); ...

```html
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a href="http://website.com/one">One</a>
            [1] => <a href="http://website.com/two">Two</a>
            [2] => <a href="http://website.com/three">Three</a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://website.com/one
            [1] => http://website.com/two
            [2] => http://website.com/three
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => One
            [1] => Two
            [2] => Three
        )

)
```

Comment: *preg_match* **_all()**

Comment: if i change it to preg_match_all then it outputs this: <name>Array</name><link>Array</link>

Comment: Do: `print_r($display);` to see what you get

Comment: @Rizier123 see my post above for the output

Comment: Yes, there are all your matches :) SubArray 0 = Full matches; SubArray 1 = first capture group; SubArray 2 = Second capture group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to get all matches and then iterate through them:

```
preg_match_all('~<a href="(.+?)">(.+?)</a>~s', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $m) {
  echo "<name>".$m[2]."</name><link>".$m[1]."</link>\n";
}
```

But I'd recommend using **DOM** for this task instead.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html); // load the HTML data

foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
  echo "<name>".$link->nodeValue."</name><link>".$link->getAttribute('href')."</link>\n";
}
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/452785)

Comment: Side Node: IMHO using `PREG_SET_ORDER` (rather than the default `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER`) delivers an easier to process result, cause you simple can `foreach'` the result Array and use single dimensional Access (`[1], [2], [3]`) to Access the match Groups. Also with named matchgroups having `$match["link"]` is easier to read than `$matches["link"][1]` etc.

Comment: @dognose I was going off OP's code but I've updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can something like this

```
$xml = '';
$show = '<a href="http://website.com/one">One</a>
         <a href="http://website.com/two">Two</a>
         <a href="http://website.com/three">Three</a>';

preg_match_all("/<a href=\"(.+?)\">(.+?)<\/a>/", $show, $display);
for($i=0; $i<count($display[0]); $i++){
    $xml .= "<name>".$display[2][$i]."</name><link>".$display[1][$i]."</link>";
}
echo $xml;
```

and this will output

```
<name>One</name><link>http://website.com/one</link><name>Two</name><link>http://website.com/two</link><name>Three</name><link>http://website.com/three</link>
```

**[DEMO](http://ideone.com/7NL9nk)**